# How to format entire date column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date-format

I want to change the date format in certain column. I used date_format syntax. The code is executing but I'm getting the o/p values as null. [Please do look into the image of my code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mD7XM.jpg)
Here is the SQL query:

```sql
select
date_format(tran_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
from
transactions
```

Comment: Date columns in MySQL do not have any "format" in the sense you imagine.

Comment: Show your transactions table column definition with data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alter change statement like this given example

MYSQL: ALTER TABLE Customer CHANGE Address Addr char(50);

ORACLE:ALTER TABLE Customer RENAME COLUMN Address TO Addr;

Refrence is this link https://www.1keydata.com/sql/alter-table-rename-column.html

Answer (score 0):

Following is the syntax for DATE_FORMAT:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, format)
```

Input type should be date. Please check the data type for column trans_date.

And if you want to change the date format for the entire column, you can execute the following:

```
update table set trans_date=date_format(trans_date,'%Y-%m-%d');
```

If the input type for trans_date is string then you can use STR_TO_DATE(string, format).